# Помогите объединить дату и время в sql запросе

Tags: mysql, yii2, запрос, select, concat

Есть такой запрос в Yii2

```
$onTvNext = Tvprog::find()
        ->where( [ 'channel_id' => $channelId ] )
        ->andWhere( ['>=', 'date', $dateNow ] )
        ->andWhere( ['>=', 'time', $timeNow ] )
        ->limit( 3 )
        ->offset( 0 )
        ->all();
```

либо он же в обычном виде

```
SELECT * FROM `tvprogram` WHERE `date` >= $dateNow AND `time` >= $timeNow AND `channel_id` = $channelId LIMIT 0,3
```

Мне нужно объединить в запросе дату и время, чтобы они были как одно значение datetime (2020-10-15 22:50:00)

Вроде как concat нужно использовать, но не пойму как его прилепить к моему запросу. Помогите плз.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP($date, $time)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp

Comment: Поясни как использовать? Дата и время в базе в разных колонках. Нужно их объединить в запросе чтобы сделать верную выборку. В моем варианте при достижении последней записи в текущей дате, не берет первые записи следующей даты. Было бы все нормально, если бы дата и время были в одном поле, но есть что есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение подсказал пользователь maleks на форуме Yii

```
use yii\db\Expression;
//...
$query->andWhere( ['>=', new Expression("CONCAT([[date]], ' ', [[time]])"), $datetime ] )
```

Comment: Вместо CONCAT как раз и нужно использовать TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Вместо `CONCAT`, если я все верно помню из синтаксиса `SQL` можно использовать `||` т.е `date||' '||time`